# Hibernate - Child records are not being deleted

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have two tables set up as Parent/Child e.g Company and Product as follows -

Company Table:-

company_id , Company_name, creation_date

101, IBM,12-May-2010

Product Table:-

company_id, Product_id, Product_name

101,            1001,       Eclipse

101,        1002,       DB2

Saving a new parent child (company and product) is not an issue. The issue comes when the user deletes a product from company object.

I have following product mapping information in Company.java

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID",nullable=false)
@OrderBy(clause = "PRODUCT_NAME" )
@ForeignKey(name = "fk_company_product")     
private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

Through this mapping, product information is being updated properly but if i delete an product from the company bean and save company then product information is not being deleted from Product table.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Cascade delete works only if you delete the parent. To handle the delete using annotations you should use:

1. If you are using JPA 2.0:

   ```
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval=true)
   ```
2. If you are using JPA 1.0 you can use the hibernate annotation:

   ```
   @OneToMany(CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
   ```

Comment: I want to do it through annotation mappings

Comment: so if i delete a product from product list and save company then product would we delete from product table right?

Comment: Yes, that's how it should happen.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you get an error or it's just ignoring the delete? Also, what versions of hibernate and jpa do you use?

Comment: JAP 2.0 and Hibernate 3.3.2. Not throwing any exception just ignoring the child delete while updating the parent.

Comment: Hibernate 3.3.2 is not a JPA 2.0 implementation, so it does not support orphanRemoval = true. Your only option should be "cascade=CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)". Have a look here, maybe it helps: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2376122